# Dolphin File Manager will not Launch

Tags: kubuntu

I have KUbuntu installed on my PC, The Dolphin file manager that came with the OS will not launch all of a sudden. Below is the error message I get, I spent a day trying to correct it. But alas I'm a DUMMY !!

```
KDEInit could not launch 'ksystraycmd':
Could not open library '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_ksystraycmd'.
Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_ksystraycmd: (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_ksystraycmd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try removing the systray flag in the launcher options. I'll try to explain through screenshots. Unfortunately I've the desktop in Italian, but since the positions are the same, I hope it helps nonetheless.

Go to the K launcher (if you have not, put Dolphin among the favorites) and click with the right button on it. Go to "Edit application":

[image]

Then Application tab -> Advanced options:

[image]

Unflag the systray related option. It is "Place in system tray":

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked for me. (I had added MATLAB to a panel in KDE, but it gave this question's error message as a dialogue popup window upon clicking on the MATLAB icon in the panel.) If I may ask, *why* does your solution work?