# Bug 359861 - :KDEInit could not launch 'ksystraycmd'

Tags: kubuntu, kde, bug-reporting

My distro=Kubuntu 16.04 LTS. Fully updated and upgraded as of 2 hours ago.

Just recently today I began to have issues with this when I attempt to run Konsole from hotkeys. I have included the bug number in the question title. Looking on the KDE bug report page, https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359861 , the bug status is "unconfirmed" yet others are having the same issues. Does anyone have a fix/work-around for this? Krunner is also having issues when I attempt to manually go into my applications menu to start konsole that way. No application windows will stay up as if they are being closed almost as soon as they are opened. I cannot access terminal to check file integrity.

```
KDEInit could not launch 'ksystraycmd':
Could not open library '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_ksystraycmd'.
Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_ksystraycmd: 
(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_ksystraycmd.so: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Comment: You should comment on the bug report, as we are not the developers. It is unconfirmed because only one person reported it, adding your report may make them look at it.

Comment: That is precisely why I am asking for a possible work-around. Not a bug fix.

Comment: OK, I agree, it should be acceptable for you to ask for a workaround. This policy is being debated but you have convinced me. Could you offer your support by voting here http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15106/should-a-question-asking-for-a-workaround-for-a-problem-in-an-in-development-ver it would help a lot :)

Comment: Related to Kmenuedit https://bugs.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/+bug/1437603 Same https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349242 Same http://askubuntu.com/questions/722241/dolphin-file-manager-will-not-launch So ... what is your kmenuedit entry for Konsole?